# How to handle linux link file in windows

Tags: linux, windows

I have tar a linux folder(with some source file in it) and copy it to windows, then I use winrar to unpack it. But when unpack some files winrar tip me that: file existing, overwrite? I think the reason is windows cannot identify linux link file, isn't it? So what should I do to avoid this case?

Comment: It could also be the case that you have both Foo.text and foo.text in the archive...

Comment: You may wish to look at [Dealing with symbolic links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467097/how-to-deal-with-symbolic-links-when-going-between-linux-and-windows) (and others), here at **stackoverflow**. And also [NTFS symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) at wikipedia.